# How to order collection by two date-fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I don't know if is possible combine two Date fields into one. And then order by this field.

Having this data:

```
{_id:1, date1:2003-1-1, date2:null},
{_id:2, date1:2002-1-1, date2:2004-1-1},
{_id:3, date1:2001-1-1, date2:2005-1-1},
{_id:4, date1:2001-1-1, date2:2002-1-1},
```

I'd like to combine date1 and date2 into one (both are Date fields). And order descending. The combination is decided by which one is greater.

So the result must be like this:

```
{_id:3, date1:2001-1-1, date2:2005-1-1},
{_id:2, date1:2002-1-1, date2:2004-1-1},
{_id:1, date1:2003-1-1, date2:null},
{_id:4, date1:2001-1-1, date2:2002-1-1},
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear. Are you trying to sort descending by length of period between the two dates `date1` and `date2`?

Comment: Descending between the two dates. _id:3 is the first one because has the greatest date.